# using multiple keyvalues for std::map C++

Tags: c++

Hi I am trying to write a function which reads data from a file and then saves it in memory. 
This memory will need a x and a y value to be identified. It may not be linear, there can be big jumps between the different x and y values and the amount of values are unknown which excludes the use of an multi-dimensional array.

I wanted to use std::map since it does what I need, but it does not support multiple key values. What else could I use to store the data or is there a way to merge the X and Y values so that it will be able to be used in a map container?

Comment: What do you mean it does not support multiple key values?

Comment: What are you planning to do with the values? A fast check if one point exists?

Comment: You need to explain to us how you plan to use this data - in other words, do you need to be able to find all items at a given `x` position? Or all items at a given `y`? Or all items "inside" the rectangle `(x1,y1,x2,y2)`? We need to know your requirements/needs in order to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a pair of the `x` and `y` values, and use that as the key:

```
std::map<std::pair<int, int>, whatever>
```

Note that as it stands, this will treat the `x` values as more significant than the `y` values if you traverse the map in order. If you want the `y` values to be more significant, you'd want to put them first in the pair.

Comment: Thank you! I thought that was only for using map::insert!

Comment: @Hjorthenify: For `insert`, you also use a pair, but that's a `pair<key,value>`, where this is composing the key of two different pieces, so with insert you'd use `srd:pair<std:pair<x, y>, value>`.

Answer (score 2):

You should use an `std::pair` as the key to your map:

```
std::map<std::pair<int, int>, value_type> m;
```

You can insert into the map using:

```
m[std::make_pair(0, 0)] = some_value;
```

If you don't care about the order of your elements and would like faster retrieval and insertion, try a `std::unordered_map` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Although you could use std::pair as suggested by the others, I would seriously consider making a simple class that contains data members for your key.  It improves readability, and also makes it easier to extend it with a 3rd, 4th, ... member if needed.

If you start with std::pair, and then you want to add a 3rd element, you could be tempted to move to std::tuple, but this can result in unreadable code.

Simply make a key class, and give it a decent constructor (one argument per data member).